# Show calculated value at the bottom of every node for a specific content type

Tags: views

I am beginner in Drupal. I am using different content types and views for my project. Here for specific content type I have created number of fields. Two of the fields are integer field type.

I want to calculate those two fields and show the calculated values at the bottom of every single node for a specific content type.

How can I achieve it? using views or by any other way.

Answer (score 0):

[**Computed Field**](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module will do for you.

> Computed Field is a very powerful field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You
>   can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the
>   database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the
>   fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

if you need this through views, you can check this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40520/how-can-i-add-a-field-to-a-view-that-is-calculated-using-other-fields) there are answers which might help you.

also this module will help you,

**[Views Custom Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_customfield)**

> Now that the Views module has incorporated the rownumber and markup
>   fields, only the PHP field is left for this module. I started a new
>   project called Views PHP. It also includes support for PHP filters and
>   sorts.

Comment: i want to show the every single node in views not by default nodeview. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

A not commonly known/used alternative to the [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module (suggested in the previous answer), is the [Math Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathfield) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> The Math Field module defines a new field type to dynamically calculate values on entity forms. **This is an alternative to [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field)
>   that does not require the use of PHP Filter.**
>
> Math expression fields are dynamically updated via ajax on the entity form as soon as all necessary fields are populated. If JavaScript is disabled, the field will be evaluated when the form is submitted. The result is stored in the database when the form is submitted.

For more details (step-by-step instructions), refer to either of these links:

- the (amazing!) [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2484065) about the Math Field module.
- the interesting article about [Introducing the Math Field module](https://www.monarchdigital.com/blog/2015-06-22/introducing-math-field-module), which also includes some screenprints to see it at work (such as the the add/edit form example).

**Bonus**: you would not need the "PHP filter" (as is the case for the  [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module), IMO only that should be a valid reason to investigate this alternative ...